# finding the variance of a random variable t, which depends on another random variable x.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I know that (U stands for uniform distribution)$$ t|x \sim U(0,\frac{1}{x})$$
while x is a random variable itself, distributed exponentially:
$$x\sim exp(\lambda)$$

now i thought using the law of total expectation in order to find the variance of t:

$$E[t] = E[E[t|x]] = E[\frac{1}{2x}]$$

and
$$ E[t^2]=E[E[t^2|x]] = E[\frac{1}{12x^2} + \frac{1}{(2x)^2}] = E[\frac{1}{3x^2}] $$

and then calculating
$$ V[t]=E[t^2]-(E[t])^2=E[\frac{1}{3x^2}]-E[\frac{1}{2x}]$$

but knowing
$$ x \sim exp(\lambda)$$

each of these terms diverges..

am I wrong? is there any other way doing this?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for help on formatting math so that it is easier to read on this site

Comment: What exactly does $U(1,1/x)$ mean? You seem to have mistakenly thought it was uniform on $[0, 1/x]$.

Comment: thank you, I fixed it.
yes, I meant uniform distribution indeed

Comment: @YanirElm The question is wrong. $Et=\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

The mean and variance of an [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) do converge.   Because $X\sim\mathcal{Exp}(\lambda)$, therefore:$$\begin{split}\mathsf E(X)&= \lambda^{-1}\\\mathsf E(X^2)-\mathsf E(X)^2&=\lambda^{-2}\end{split}$$

---

Also since $T\mid X\sim\mathcal U(1,\tfrac 1X)$ therefore: $\mathsf E(T\mid X)=\dfrac X2$ and $\mathsf E(T^2\mid X)=\dfrac{X^2}{3}$

Comment: Isn't the OP trying to compute $E[1/X]$ and $E[1/X^2]$?

Comment: yes I mean E[1/x]

Comment: Why?  Oh... I see... No.

Comment: maybe there's an error in the question itself..

Comment: No, the question is fine.  The mistake is that $\mathsf E(T\mid X)=X/2$ and not $1/(2X)$.

Comment: oh sorry, it's only now I noticed I had a typo, it's $$U(0,1/x)$$ , shouldn't the expected value be $$\frac{\frac{1}{x}-0}{2}$$? thanks for your help